# Connecting drawn lines from a tablet in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing-tablet

I recently bought a Wacom tablet for someone I know as she is interested in getting into the digital design industry. She's mainly just been doodling some drawings in Photoshop with it at the moment, but she wants to start adding colour to the drawings. However, she told me that due to the brush strokes the lines are not completely connected (for example if she draws a circle as a face, there are gaps in some places). What method do people use to get around this, and to start adding colour?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the style of the drawing she wants to make. I usually go from line drawing to line drawing and painting hybrid ( It still has lines showing, I color heavily over the lines and it's still not very detailed at this point  ). Then I continue by painting more and more over it to get rid of the lines and add more detail. Which essentially means that for me, the initial line quality is irrelevant.

Comment: Doodling some drawings and adding a flat paint-bucket color to it might be better achieved in Illustrator, you won't have to worry about pixel edge color and falloff.

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop, one technique concept artists use is to put your fill/paint on a layer below the linework. Simply draw (or scan) in a black and white image, then set the blend mode to multiply and lock it. All the white will be transparent, while the tonal info will remain.

Create a layer underneath and paint away. You can also set up a layer mask(s) to keep you painting inside the lines of specific areas. This is a good solution because your lines don't have to be closed and you can paint really quickly and rely on layer masks, which you only set up once at the start, to keep you in the lines.

Answer (score 1):

This can really vary depending on what paint style you are trying to achieve.
here are a few options.

- Paint with the brush, not with the paint bucket.
- Duplicate the layer with the drawing and connect/fill the holes on
  that layer, Then use the paint bucket.

here are some Tutorials on different techniques
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/advanced-digital-painting-tutorials/